# How to disable ripple effect tabbedbar Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have a Tabbed Bar, with a press on its buttons, the ripple effect appears. 
I want to completely disable this effect.

I need a custom renderer for android.

[image]

Comment: Is this only on Galaxy?

Comment: @Prateek On android in general.

Comment: Probably having custom renderer would solve it for you. [Example](https://xamgirl.com/extending-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/) , you can also check solutions in this [github issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2096#issuecomment-602238877)

Comment: @Prateek Thanks, I realized that I need to use a custom renderer, but I don’t know which property I need to apply in order to disable the effect.

Comment: I believe you would want to [turn off Shift effect](https://montemagno.com/xamarin-forms-fully-customize-bottom-tabs-on-android-turn-off-shifting/) and also add try adding some coding mentioned in that Github issue

Comment: @Prateek 
This github issue code will be used for regular buttons. I don’t quite understand how to apply it to tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.

In Custom Renderer:

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            _bottomNavigationView = (GetChildAt(0) as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout).GetChildAt(1) as BottomNavigationView;

            ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)_bottomNavigationView.GetChildAt(0);
            int tabsCount = vg.ChildCount;
            for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++)
            {
                ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup)vg.GetChildAt(j);
                vgTab.SetBackgroundResource(App1.Droid.Resource.Drawable.hideRipple);
            }
        }
    }
```

In drawable/hideRipple.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
  <color android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: Please remember to mark your reply as answer, it may be helpful to other community members, thanks.